# How do I edit an already existing diagram in matplotlib (python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I already have an existing figure that I have created in matplotlib. I have called `plt.show()`on it already. What I want to do is to be able to add another line on it without deleting the first figure. Here is my code already:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=complex(5,6)
b=complex(2,2)
c=complex(7,-2)


def plot_vector(start, end):
    plt.plot([start.real, end.real], [start.imag, end.imag])
    plt.ylabel('i')
    plt.xlabel('r')
    plt.title('My first graph!')
    plt.ylim(-8,8)
    plt.xlim(-8,8)
    plt.show()


plot_vector(b,c)
#here the figure shows
#after the figure shows, I need to have some code run that asks the user for input
#then, I want the figure to be updated with:
plot_vector(a,c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Plotting to the same figure and axes will help you keep track of what the figure looks like at any point in time. The below script plots the first vector and saves the figure, then then plots the second vector to the same figure and saves it again.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=complex(5, 6)
b=complex(2, 2)
c=complex(7,-2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_title('My first graph!')
ax.set_ylabel('i')
ax.set_xlabel('r')
ax.set_ylim(-8,8)
ax.set_xlim(-8,8)
    
def plot_vector(start, end):
    ax.plot([start.real, end.real], [start.imag, end.imag])

plot_vector(b,c)

fig.savefig('fig1')

plot_vector(a,c)
ax.set_title('Updated')

fig.savefig('fig2')
```

If you are working in Jupyter and want to see changes as you go you will only be able to use plt.show() once. But if you assigned the figure to a variable per above, then you can always see the figure again by calling

```
fig
```

in its own cell and that will show the figure with any additional changes.